# Changing control property of current record only in Access report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a report that shows multiple records with multiple controls. In this report, a button that changes a property of one of those controls:

```
   Private Sub DetailsButton_Click()

   Me.Details.Visible = True

   End Sub
```

However, that affects all records. Is there a way to make it affect only the current record?

Thank you

Comment: What is the "current record" when it's not visible?

Comment: What criteria determines whether data should display? Perhaps a simple IIf() expression would serve: `IIf(this is true, [fieldname], Null)`. Why would you want user to determine if value should display?

Comment: The records display fine. One of the controls ("Details") is set to NOT visible when form is opened. When I click the DetailsButton, I want that Details control to go to visible, but only in the current record. Currently, when I click the button, the Details control turns visible to all of them.

Comment: @June7 I figured it would be an if statement, but I'm not sure how to tell "if the controls are in this record, apply this change, else, do nothing" (or even if that's possible). It's just a way for the user to see the details of the record, while making it visually clean of it at first.

Comment: How should code know what is 'current' record? Records are not selectable in PrintPreview. If there were some criteria to base visibility on, code in report OnFormat event could set visibility for control in each record. OnFormat event triggers only in PrintPreview or direct to printer, not ReportView.

Comment: Why would display of a single control be NOT visually clean? Just not understanding the need. Maybe need pictures.

Comment: Once again: If the cetails section contains a button and the section is hidden, you can't click on it. Nevertheless, like @June7 said: In report view, there is no "current record". When the report is rendered, you can format (or cancel) the details section of each single record using the *Format* event. Are you maybe talking about a form (not a report)?

Comment: Thanks for the attention. The button is outside the details section, but inside the current record. That's why I suppose there is a way to say "only this record". I asked the question about one control for the sake of simplicity, but it's actually several controls. The pic is before/after I click the details button. Notice it expands all records. It's in report view, yes, but maybe I'm attempting to do something only forms can do(?) https://pasteboard.co/Hxv5LEE.jpg

Comment: Perhaps I should be doing this in a simple continuous form. Even so, I wouldn't know how to refer to current record only (or if it's possible)

Comment: If you want the visibility to be dynamic for each record, need some criteria based on data to control this. What you desire - for user to arbitrarily set visibility by button click setting Visibility property - really is not possible. Why not just display the field?

Comment: Perhaps you want some behavior like datasheet/subdatasheet form?